# How would I limit users' sudo permissions for journalctl to a specific unit?

Tags: linux, systemd, sudo, systemd-journald

I want to provide our users access to `journalctl` of a specific unit. For e.g., `httpd`. My initial thought was to specify the command spec like this:

```
/usr/bin/journalctl -u httpd.service *
```

This will give them access to useful options such as `--all`, `--full`, `--follow`, etc.. However, quickly noticed that it will also allow them to specify a different unit (e.g., `-u tomcat`).

Is by specifying each of the acceptable options the only way to do this? Or can I leverage something like ACLs on a file for more granular access?

Comment: `sudo`, unfortunately, is not very granular. using wildcards kills the limitations to a great extent. if you want your users to run `/usr/bin/journalctl -u httpd.service --all`, `/usr/bin/journalctl -u httpd.service  --full`, or `/usr/bin/journalctl -u httpd.service --follow` you will need to specify each variation on a separate line in your `sudoers` file.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm afraid of. I was hoping that there was a file I could use ACLs on or systemd settings I could leverage for this.

Comment: An alternative may be to write a wrapper script that calls journalctl on httpd.service and accepts/allows only certain options. Then configure sudo to allow "any" argument to that script.

Comment: What do you fear about letting users look at other units? Problem diagnosis could easily need other units' logs. Adding the users to the `systemd-journal` group (in Ubuntu, YMMV) will grant read access to `journalctl`, and you won't have to use `sudo`. For example, if the `httpd` logs just show "network down/timeout", one would have to look at the `NetworkManager` logs.

Comment: Consider a wrapper script, that checks for safe arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a `setuid` (or `setgid`?) executable to sanitize the environment, then run the `journalctl` command. You would have to parse the `journalctl` options that the user is allowed to to specify, and pass them on.

**WARNING**

Do not, never ever, write a `setuid` script (anything that begins with hash-bang ("`#!`")). If you need an interpreter for your `setuid` script, Black Hat can easily subvert it.

The 1st 4 bytes of your `setuid` object must be "`\177ELF`" .